# How to return variable return value from JNI function?

Tags: java-native-interface, pass-by-reference

My JNI method is:

```
public native int MD_GetState(int index, int result);
```

My C function is:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_test_MD_1GetState
(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint index, jint result)
{
    jint* state, errCode;
    jint ret = GetInfo(Index, state, errCode);
    if(ret != 0) {
        result = errCode;
    } else {
        result = state;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

`GetInfo(...)` is a function in a DLL, which for the purpose of this question is a black-box implementation. I would like to return the value of either `state` or `errCode` depending on whether this function returns 0 (no error) or otherwise.

Is this the correct way to do it, or is there a better way to implement this?

---

@user207421 In my Java code I have the following method:

```
public native int methodA(int index, int type, byte[] value);
```

And the corresponding C function:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_test_methodA
(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint index, jint type, jbyteArray array)
{
    jboolean isCopy;
    jsize len = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, array);
    jbyte* bp = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, array, &isCopy);
    if (!bp) {
        return MDR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
    }

    jint ret = GetValueA(index, type, bp, len);
    int mode = 0;
    // if error code is returned then do not save changes
    if(ret != 0) {
        mode = JNI_ABORT;
    }
    (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, array, bp, mode);

    return ret;
}
```

`GetValueA(...)` makes changes to `bp` and I am able to return the data back to my Java code in the same way, so I imagine it should be a similar implementation?

---

@cdhowie According to the documentation I have, the possible values for `state` and `errCode` do not overlap, so I thought it was possible to implement it this way. If there is a better way to do this then please let me know, thanks!

Comment: You can't. Java is pass by value. The assignment to `result` won't be seen at the caller. You will have to encode both values into one return value, or throw an exception containing the error code, or return an object with both fields.

Comment: How would you differentiate the two cases in the Java code that uses this method? How would the caller know whether the int was a "state" or an "error code?" If the result is an error, would not throwing an exception be more appropriate?

Comment: @user207421 I've edited the question to include my reply. Please let me know what you think, thanks!

Comment: @cdhowie I've added a clarification to my question, hopefully it answers your question!

Comment: @user10931326 Yes, modifying *arrays* are fine, as they are passed by reference.

Comment: @user10931326 Then as long as the domain for both cases have an empty intersection, then there's nothing wrong with just returning the value, as long as you're fine with the calling code having to do the work to figure out what the value is. It might be better to throw anyway, just so the caller doesn't have to ask "did this call succeed" -- that's why exceptions exist.

Answer (score 1):

You have few options here.

1. You can throw exception from `JNI` code in case there is an error and add error code inside `Exception`

> Take a look here: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-019/

2. You can create something 'like' union. It will not be an union (sensu stricto), but will serve similar purpose

**Java**

```
  class RetVal {
  int index;
  int result;
}
```

and then, you will have to access fields of this class inside `JNI` code.

You will be able to update values of the object and return (via object) values as you like.

Note that you can alter the object's state inside `JNI`

> Take a look here: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-020/

3. You can use type size hack

You can return `long` instead of `int`. This way, you can compose your `long` value from two `int` values.

```
int a = 1;
int b = 1;
long ret = ((long)a) << 32 | ((long)b);
```

4. You can alter array of `int` values

> Take a look here: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-013/

5. You can return values inside `java.util.Vector`

> Take a look here: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-no-045/